# Is the 2011 macbook air 11" 4 gig sufficient for xcode development and PS?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I would like to use it an an iOS development machine (as i own no other mac) but i need to know if it will be sufficient for iOS dev.
And is it sufficient for PS?

Answer (score 4):

I have tried Xcode development with 4 GB and I can say it is possible. After I upgraded to 8 GB, however, I noticed that things like launching the iPhone Simulator performed much better. I would be a bit more concerned about the 11" screen, actually.

With my 13" screen, it is frustrating to not get as much visual area to display my code. I find myself switching the top and right sidebars in Xcode 4 on and off all the time.

So all in all, my advice would be against it *without an external monitor*. With an external monitor, I would give it a try--the SSD might compensate for the 4 GB of RAM and make it sufficient. Hope this helps.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend software development anyway with one screen, even if it's 40".

Comment: How many screens do you use? For me one 27" 1920x1080 suffice.

Comment: Maybe I just love developing. Cause I do it on a machine with 5 displays (2 being 27" ones), through to many steps all the way down to my 11" MBA. There are merits to every combination. So, like everything the most accurate answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 2):

To add to Christian's answer, the screen is the worry for me as well. 11" is small. you would almost have to have at least one other monitor to really use it as a full time dev machine without going blind (seriously). 4 gigs is enough, and the processor is fine.  Also, here is a great post on the exact question basically by a well known iPhone developer (Jeff LaMarche, author) [Jeff LaMarche's blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/04/macbook-air-11-as-dev-machine.html)

Comment: hey jesse the article you link to basically says it is feasible to do SW on 11 inch machine, maybe not much recommended though. But feasible at least - did I get it wrong?

Comment: I have a 13" air and I do work on it occasionally, but it is not my preferred machine. To me it is fine for actual coding, if you are getting into nibs/storyboards it becomes a pain (especially ipad). At work, I use a 15" macbook pro connected to a 27" thunderbolt so perhaps it's just being spoiled. Having an external monitor with the 13" air really really helps though.

Answer (score 2):

I use a "13 MBA 2011 with 4gb.  Performance is no issue as it sails through xcode 4 with ease, the SSD is a huge improvement over conventional hard disks.

I wouldn't recommend "11 though for development without an external monitor, purely because of the screensize.

Answer (score 0):

I use a 2011 15" Macbook Pro 4gig and it's fine for Xcode. However, I do use an external screen and would say that it wouldn't be as great if I didn't. So, using an 4gig MBA for developing is fine, but the 11" is really too small, even with an external screen.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use the 13" Macbook with 2Gb of RAM with the 2.4Ghz processor. It should run fine on any of the Intel based Macs. Obviously performance will be improved on better/newer machines. But you will run into frustration with the limited screen size. I would consider an external monitor or get really good with Spaces.